# replace contact form with thank you

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm still very new to php so this has been a struggle for me. I now need to make it so that a message appears where the form was, saying thank you.

this is the link: www.pamper-pad.co.uk/contact.php  code is as follows:

PHP:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "joxxorz@me.com";

$email_subject = "Enquiry for Pamper Pad";




$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>

<?php

}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" style="font-size:14px; height:35px;">

<table width="250px">

<tr>

<td height="25" valign="top">

<label for="first_name" style="height:35px;"><span class="boldp">Name <span class="asterisk">*</span></span></label>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td height="50" valign="top">

<input class="formbox" type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">

</td>
</tr>




<tr>

<td height="25" valign="top">

<label for="email" style="height:35px;"><span class="boldp">Telephone Number/Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span></span></label>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td height="50" valign="top">

<input class="formbox" type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

</td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td height="25" valign="top">

<label for="comments"><span class="boldp">Message <span class="asterisk">*</span></span></label>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td height="119" valign="top">

<textarea  class="formbox" name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="38" rows="6"></textarea>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td height="24" colspan="2" style="text-align:right">

<input  class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Can anyone please advise how I would replace this form with a message?

EDIT:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['email'])){
//code to display your form here
//for example
echo "<div class="formthing">
<form name="contactform" method="post" style="font-size:14px; height:35px;">

<table width="250px">

<tr>

<td height="25" valign="top">

<label for="first_name" style="height:35px;"><span class="boldp">Name <span class="asterisk">*</span></span></label>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td height="50" valign="top">

<input class="formbox" type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">

</td>
</tr>




<tr>

<td height="25" valign="top">

<label for="email" style="height:35px;"><span class="boldp">Telephone Number/Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span></span></label>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td height="50" valign="top">

<input class="formbox" type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

</td>

</tr>


<tr>

<td height="25" valign="top">

<label for="comments"><span class="boldp">Message <span class="asterisk">*</span></span>            </label>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td height="119" valign="top">

<textarea  class="formbox" name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="38" rows="6"></textarea>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td height="24" colspan="2" style="text-align:right">

<input  class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
</div>";
}elseif(isset($_POST['email'])){
//code to display thank you message here
//for example
echo "<div>Thank you for submitting your email!</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Just check to see if the email was sent, if so, display the thank you message. If not, display the form. A basic if/else will do.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to header injection.

Comment: Hi John - I'm totally clueless with PHP unfortunately so I have no idea on how to run those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the form in a div and another div with a thank you message.

Then check

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['name) && email etc){
    echo '<div class="thank you"> Thank you </div>}
    else
    {
    echo '<div class="divform"> form </div>
    }

?php>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always sanitize your post values.

For instance:

```
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
```

Should be:

```
$email_from = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)
```

To further sanitize and check you can:

```
if ($_POST['email'] == $email_from && filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
   $verified_email_from = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}
```

Though @PeeHaa may be able to specify further.

And for these:

```
$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
```

You can use:

```
$first_name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
$comments= filter_var($_POST['comments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
```

You can read more on sanitizing at [PHP.NET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) and there is a nice tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-clean-with-php--net-6732)

Aside that as @terisL has stated you can use the post var to display a different page depending on status. You would build each page in PHP and it would choose to display based on post status.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['email'])){
    //code to display your form here
    //for example
echo "<form name='contactform' method='post' style='font-size:14px; height:35px;'>

<table width='250px'>

<tr>

<td height='25' valign='top'>

<label for='first_name' style='height:35px;'><span class='boldp'>Name <span class='asterisk'>*</span></span></label>

</td>

</tr>";
}elseif(isset($_POST['email'])){
    //code to display thank you message here
    //for example
    echo "<div>Thank you for submitting your email!</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Robert,  I'm confused. Does this just sit in my html? Thank you for your help so far though!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I will try to re-explain. Your current HTML code will 'not exist'. It will be 'built' by PHP using "ECHO" in my example. "ECHO" will write the code to the page and it will appear as regular HTML. For example to say "Hello" in html on a page you code "<h1>Hello</h1>" to do it in PHP you code "<?php echo '<h1>Hello</h1>';" and the PHP will write it to the page for you. The PHP code I provided above will sit in your HTML where you want the form to show. [This page](http://www.ntchosting.com/php/php-in-html.html) goes a little more in depth.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for all our help so far! I'm still quite struggling. The page is no longer displaying actually. Please see my edits above, there must be something wrong in there but I'm not sure.

Comment: It will function as normal HTML (css included). In your example you have the same quotes in PHP as in your HTML. Take a look at my example again. Notice the single and double quotes. The easiest way to fix that for you would be to replace the outside quotes " with ' single quotes to wrap your entire HTML block.